# RegEx to find or match an upper-domain that is followed by a specific word (anchor)

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I have a text block, or string:

```
(Ex.1) domain of doorstops-scripts.asjewelries.com designates 88.198.68.211 as permitted sender
(Ex.2) domain of aiceo.net designates 193.105.73.148 as permitted sender
```

I would like to match/find the upper domain: `asjewelries.com` or `aiceo.net`).

That is `.com`, `.net`, `.info`, `.tv`, etc. (2-5 chars preceded by a dot) with either preceeding chars following a dot (`asjewelries` in Ex.1) or if there are no lower domains following a space (`aiceo` in Ex.2)

Both domains are followed by a specific word (anchor): `designates`. They could be followed immediately by this anchor or there may be other words between.

this is the goal:

```
asjewelries.com (Ex.1)
aiceo.net (Ex.2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to match/find the upper domain (`asjewelries.com` or `aiceo.net`) only

How about matching everything after "`domain of`" and up to the first space? It would narrow down false positives.

```
domain of (?:\S+\.)?([^ .]+\.[^ .]{2,5})
```

Notice how I'm using a [`( group )`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to create a backreference for the domain. Everything else in that pattern matches any character except spaces and uses the "`.`" to fetch the domain.

Alternatively, if the text "`domain of`" varies, you can simply remove it:

```
\s(?:\S+\.)?([^ .]+\.[^ .]{2,5})\s
```

> The important thing is that both domains are followed by 
>   a specific word (anchor) that in this case is the word "`designates`".
>   They could be followed immediately by this anchor 
>   or there may be other words in between.
>
> > word "designate" does not immediately follow the domain

Easy, just check for the occurrence of the word "`designate`" or "`designates`" by matching it literally in the pattern.

#### Regex:

```
domain of (?:\S+\.)?([^ .]+\.[^ .]{2,5}) .*?\bdesignates?\b
```

**Important:** Get the text returned by the first backreference (1st group). In AHK it should be returned by `match[1]`.

[Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/jW1uA2/1)

#### Output:

```
"asjewelries.com"
"aiceo.net"
```

---

I'm positive you could create these kind of expressions if you read a couple of minutes about regex syntax, so allow me to recommend:

1. [Regular Expressions Tutorial (regular-expressions.info)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). A quite comprehensive tutorial to learn regex.
2. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). Allows you to test different expressions and understand the way a pattern matches the subjet string.

Comment: Thanks, Mariano for your helpful tips and thoughtful pointers. karthik manchala's solution \w*[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\w{2,5}(?=\s) did the trick! I dabble in AHK; not a hard-core hacker.

Comment: I thought the string should have the word "`designates`". That regex does not validate it. Test against string "`domain of foo.com ignores 123 as permitted sender`"... As for the language, I asked because the answer may vary for every regex flavour. AHK uses a powerful library (PCRE).

Comment: Yes, I was desperate and had to use an anchor word in the string (in this case "designates") to get anywhere. I had an awkward 3-step solution as follows (LOL): (1) RegExMatch(String,"(?:\S+\s)?\S*\bdesignates\b",match)
(2) StringTrimRight, FoundDomain, match, 11
(3) RegExMatch(FoundDomain, "[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$", FoundDomain)

Comment: @Bruno All attempts are valid, the important thing is you keep trying. Just keep in mind that `\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\w{2,5}(?=\s)` would also match the string "`O123.45 `".

Comment: Also, regarding AHK and the use of match[1], I am somewhat familiar and the code I have seen uses iO) (O standing for Object). I have one using right now (not my code) using match[1] to grab domain names as well: RegExMatch(String,"iO)\RFrom:[^\r\n]*[\w.%+-]+@((?:(?!sbcglobal)[A-Z\d.-])+\.[A-Z]{2,4})", Found) >> Result:
MsgBox, % Found[1]

Comment: Thanks, tried to create the tag, but it says: Creating the new tag 'ahk' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

Comment: Also, thanks for the heads-up on O123.45. I guess I can build on or modify the code in different variations to fit my needs, such as: RegExMatch(String,"\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*[a-zA-Z]\.\w*[a-zA-Z]{2,5}(?=\s)",match)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = " Ex. 1) domain of doorstops-scripts.asjewelries.com designates 88.198.68.211 as permitted sender Ex. 2) domain of aiceo.net";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((Ex\\.\\s1\\)).*\\.(asjewelries\\.\\w{1,4}).*(Ex\\.\\s2\\)).*(aiceo.\\w{1,4}))");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    if ( matcher.find() ) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)+ " (" +matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5)+ " (" + matcher.group(4));
    }
}
```

should output

```
asjewelries.com (Ex. 1)
aiceo.net (Ex. 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for you your help. I forgot to add these are only examples. In the real-world application, I have no idea what those domains are. All I know is that they are of the format xxx-xxx.xxx, xxx-xxx.yy, xxx.xxx, xxx.yy, etc. But I do know there is an anchor word "designates" always following them (maybe immediately maybe not). All the lengths are unknown and variable other than domain names: .com, .net, .info, .tv, etc. (dot followed by 1-4 chars).

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. What about "asjewelries" and "aiceo"? They are still in the code. We don't know these names. They are only examples. They could be any name (string) and of any length. The only known is anchor word "designates" and it does not show in the code.

Comment: The closest code I got from this site is the following, but the problem is first it assumes "designates" follows immediately the domain (not working if there are other strings in between) and it is also included in the match. How can I exclude anchor word "designates" from the match at least in this code: RegExMatch(String,"(?:\S+\s)?\S*designates",match)

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile  (".+[\\.|\\s](\\w+\\.\\w{1,4})\\s+designates");     This must be the answer you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! I ran your code in AHK so I had to modify as follows, but it returns from the very beginning of the string up to and including "designates": RegExMatch(String,".+[\.|\s](\w+\.\w{1,4})\s+designates",match)

Comment: it works perfectly, but you must make use of matcher.group(1) to get the group that is in parentheses. If you run it just like that, everything would display.. Note the matcher.group(1) is just an example. You must group it in AHK. This grouping is done in java

Comment: Thanks! Is there any Lookbehind trick to do it all in one line of RegEx? Also, does your code work if the anchor word "designate" does not immediately follow the domain? Such as: Ex. 3) Received-SPF: none (domain of catalyst-vm1.featsatisfied.com does not designate permitted sender hosts)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
\w*[a-zA-Z]\w*\.\w{2,5}(?=\s)
```

See [RegEx DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nI5dH1/7)

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks, karthik, it did the job exactly as I was looking for. I ran your code in AHK scripting language and it beautifully offered the exact solution. It also solved my other issue, and that is your code is not dependent on any anchor word such as "designates" etc. as I thought it was!